# How can I get my camera to stop following my player when I jump on the Y axis in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, 2d

Real quick. I'm making a 2D game where my player is moving downwards along the Y-axis. Nothing brings the player back up so I would like to lock my camera on the player. When my player jumps, the camera follows which is basically what i'm trying to prevent but I cant seem to find an "easy" solution for this. Thanks in advance if anyone can help me out!'

```
  public Transform target;

  public bool X, Y, Z;

  public float XOffset, YOffset, ZOffset;

  void Update()
  {
        transform.position = new Vector3(
            (X ? target.position.x + XOffset : transform.position.x),
            (Y ? target.position.y + YOffset : transform.position.y),
            (Z ? target.position.z + ZOffset : transform.position.z));

  }
```

Comment: you need to provide some minimal code that can be used to help you with your issue.

Comment: Trying to do some type of "disable y axis" when jumping but has not been working.  Need a cleaner way to achieve this

Comment: Could you explain the connection between `Nothing brings the player back up` and `When my player jumps` ... so does a jump not bring the player back up ...?

Comment: It's a 2D skiing game so to create the illusion of a jump the player moves up slightly on the Y axis but is never actually traveling upwards (at least for more than a second) If that make sense.

Comment: Didnt you ask the same question earlier https://stackoverflow.com/a/59411066/687262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Y` is true, have the y component be the minimum of the current y position and the target's y position plus offset.

```
public Transform target;

public bool X, Y, Z;

public float XOffset, YOffset, ZOffset;

void Update() 
{ 
    Vector3 targetPos = target.position;
    Vector3 currentPos = transform.position;

    transform.position = new Vector3(
            X ? targetPos.x + XOffset : currentPos.x, 
            Y ? Mathf.Min(currentPos.y, targetPos.y + YOffset) : currentPos.y,
            Z ? targetPos.z + ZOffset : currentPos.z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store camera's last transform position and check if its higher than before. Then you can change Y value according to it.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 LastCameraPosition = Vector3.positiveInfinity;

    public Transform target;

    public bool X, Y, Z;

    public float XOffset, YOffset, ZOffset;

    void Update()
    {

        if (target.position.y < LastCameraPosition.y)
        {
            LastCameraPosition = target.position;
            Y = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Y = false;
        }

        transform.position = new Vector3(
       (X ? target.position.x + XOffset : transform.position.x),
       (Y ? target.position.y + YOffset : transform.position.y),
       (Z ? target.position.z + ZOffset : transform.position.z));
    }
}
```

Comment: This also works out.  Thank you very much for your time as well.

Comment: Glad we helped. Ruzihm's way is much more efficient. You should use his algorithm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to update a gounded_y variable every frame the player is on the ground and use that as the minimal or maximal (depending on direction) for the y of the camera.
This way the cam will follow if the player falls down after a jump but will never follow upwards during a jump.

Comment: unless he hits a plane that is higher, then he would be grounded again. you would need to check if the last grounded_y variable is < than the new one.

Answer (score -1):

if your player is always going downwards you can add a condition to the camera update

```
if(character.transform.position.y < camera.transform.position.y){
    camera.transform.position = new Vector3(
            character.position.x + XOffset,
            character.position.y + YOffset,
            character.position.z + ZOffset);
}
```

of course in this case the camera isn't allowed to be a child object of the player

Comment: This still allows the camera to up move up on the Y axis when the player jumps (which is what i'm trying to avoid)

Comment: @Evan how so? you only update the transform of your camera when player position is lower than the last camera position

Comment: Sigh idk, just tried it out and the camera still follows the player when jumping.

Comment: @nka_Zz It would have been closer if you did `if (character.transform.position.y + YOffset < camera.transform.position.y)` but even then, asker wants the camera to follow the character in x and z while the player is jumping.

Comment: @Ruzihm that was not apparent from his question and when i wrote the answer he hadn't cleared that up in the comments yet. I mean he wrote  "When my player jumps, the camera follows which is basically what i'm trying to prevent"